# ASP.NET - Learning .NET Framework 3.0 / 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, .net-3.0

I would like to learn ASP.NET (Complete .NET Framework 3.0 / 3.5) and not getting time to attend training classes in any training center.

Kindly let me know if you know if there are any other good alternates/options to learn.

Kindly provide the details too.

Comment: Dear unknown from (google), do a google search for "learn asp.net 3.5"...

Answer (score 3):

you can start at http://www.asp.net/get-started/

Answer (score 2):

To really learn any language and supporting platform you need to code, and code a lot.  Resources are quite numerous out there, so in this sense I can understand your questions, i.e. what are some recommendations.  Below is a list I would consider to get that initial push that will enable you to begin your journey to becoming a solid coder.

1) Microsoft's MSDN, Codeplex, ASP.NET website, and development tools are where I would start. Microsoft offers all the tools needed to build/code in the .NET framework which you can freely download.  Their online documentation has really become a solid resource and their examples, along with others, can be found at Codeplex.com.  The ASP.NET also has a wealth of resources and a pretty good forum for user discussion and knowledge sharing.

2) SourceForge:  Look for Open Source initiatives and become involved in them.  At first you will be learning but if dedicated, i.e. you like the project, you will be helping others in short order.  An example of a Microsoft ASP.NET Open Source initiative I would recommend is DotNetNuke.  The core team members are very nice and the community as a whole very helpful and continually growing.  You may even find one day that you are developing and selling your own custom modules for extending DotNetNuke at snowcovered.com - so there is a monetary benefit I've provided for your efforts!

3) Learnvisualstudio.net:  I joined this several years back and purchased a life-time membership for very little.  This site offers video based training which is not bad.  In addition to life-time memberships there are other plans which might suite your needs and all of which are very affordable. BTW, they have had a new series out for a few months on Visual Studio 2010 .NET 4 - "First Impressions Visual Studio 2010 - ASP.NET 4.0".  They also offer two video formats; one for desktop programs, i.e. Win Media Player and VLC, and one for mobile devices such as iPhone/iPod Touch.

4) Informit's Books Online or Books24x7.com:  As a possible alternative to purchasing books at Borders/Amazon/etc. you might find the option of an electronic bookshelf a valuable resource in which you can load up your own bookshelf with much more technical books that you'll ever need.  The all inclusive offerings are about $40/month or $500/yr. They both have a trial period so you can see what each is like since they both have their +/-'s.  Consider how much you normally spend on technical books a year for starters and go with a comparable plan (Informit's Books Online has more pricing options, I believe).  If you find a book you wish to have in hand, you can purchase it for a reduced member's price.  Finally, if you own a mobile device such as a Blackberry, iPhone, etc. you can browse your bookshelf with your device in a format they provide, which is live online and very readable (in contrast with Apple’s safari book bag used to browse downloaded PDF versions of content purchased at Safari’s Books Online -  which I find sorta tough to read).

5) Get a nice computer of your own if you can afford it.  I like Dell desktops and Lenovo Thinkpad notebooks, and if not sure what manufacturer to go with take a look at reviews by CNET.  An investment like this might give you a little added push from behind to learn and you can configure your machine as you wish.  Windows 7 is terrific and you can use Virtual PC 2007, which is a free tool you can use to host server and other OS’es if you wish to develop in SharePoint or learn other server based technologies.

My final comment is that not a single one of these resources will mean anything if you believe that just by purchasing something you will learn how to code.  This list represents just some random thoughts and it is just a begining.  It takes time, dedication, and honesty with yourself about your goals … and expect to be frustrated at times.  A good friend who shares similar aspirations as you can make a huge difference when embarking down the path to becoming a good "anything”.  It is heavy lifting at times and you’ll want a spotter around when it is so.

Start small and be reasonable with your expectations.  Best of luck!

John

Answer (score 1):

I found this publication to be very helpful:

[Pro ASP.NET 3.5 in C# (Apress)](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781590598931)

I like this author's writing style since it's put in straightfoward, understandable terms. You can download some sample material on the Apress site. Additionally, it looks like used copies can be had for a pretty decent price as well if you check on Amazon.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have this book, and I agree it's easy to understand and has been very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to learn any framework is to write in it.

Best advice I can give is to go the web site start [here](http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-videos/video-14.aspx), and move forward.

Keep writing applications in it and you will learn it.